# VSCode FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, arcade

I am trying to create a 2D arcade style game for a project in school using Python Arcade in VSCode, but I have issues correctly locating a map I created on a map editor.

Both the game code and map file are situated in the same main folder, with the map being placed in a sub-folder within the main folder.

[image: image of file structure]

I have used this line of code to specify the map location:

```
# Map name
    map_name = ("maps/map1_level_{}.tmx.".format(level))
```

This is the error:

```
C:\Users\frag>python c:/Users/frag/Documents/game/arcade_game.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/frag/Documents/game/arcade_game.py", line 310, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/frag/Documents/game/arcade_game.py", line 305, in main
    window.setup(window.level)
  File "c:/Users/frag/Documents/game/arcade_game.py", line 120, in setup
    my_map = arcade.tilemap.read_tmx(map_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\arcade\tilemap.py", line 56, in read_tmx
    tmx_file = resolve_resource_path(tmx_file)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\arcade\resources\__init__.py", line 30, in resolve_resource_path
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"Cannot locate resource : {path}")
FileNotFoundError: Cannot locate resource : maps\map1_level_1.tmx
```

Comment: What is your question/problem exactly?

Comment: It is unable to locate the map file, error output has been added

Answer (score 0):

try this  `map_name = ("./maps/map1_level_{}.tmx.".format(level))`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by specifying the working absolute path:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/frag/Documents/game')
```